# Can I obtain the cross sections of my reaction if I have the Mandelstam variable from a simulation?

Tags: particle-physics, kinematics, scattering-cross-section

I am working in a $a+b\to c+d$ process and I was able to obtain the initial and final four-momentum of the reaction, and thus $s$, $t$, and $u$. But I was wondering, can I calculate the cross-section of my system from these variables?

Comment: The question sounds a bit weird. Look at your formula for the cross section. Do you know all the necessary variables? In that case yes, you can calculate it.

Comment: @Javier I think i may have expressed myself badly. The Mandelstam variables have information about the scattering angles right? I have the Mandelstam variables for all N events in my simulation, with that, could i obtain the differential cross section with that angle information ?